# Check if a LocalDateTime is between work hours

Tags: android, kotlin

I wonder what's the more efficient way to compare values to check if the current date is in a range of values.

I'd like to trigger a local notification only from Monday to Friday and from 8:00 to 18:00 (8a.m. - 6p.m.)

First I was writing this :

```
val current = LocalDateTime.now()
val day = current.dayOfWeek.value
val hour = current.hour

if(day != 6 && day != 7 && hour > 7 && hour < 18) 
   {...}
```

But Android Studio suggested
`hour in 8..17`

So should I use `day != 6 && day != 7 && hour > 7 && hour < 18`
Or `day != 6 && day != 7 && hour in 8..17`,
Or `day in 1..5 && hour in 8..17`,
Or something else?

What do you think?

Comment: It's a matter of opinion, but I think `day in 1..5 && hour in 8..17` is easiest to read and comprehend so it's best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the many ways you do this, you won't observe any as being "more efficient" (unless you are doing millions of evaluations).

I agree with @Tenfour04 that a much bigger consideration is readability - so that you/others can reason that the code is correct.  Consider also using named constants for the days of the week (`DayOfWeek.MONDAY`) you can still use these in ranges.  How about this then:

```
val current = LocalDateTime.now()
val isInWorkingHours = current.hour in 8..17
val isWorkingDay = current.dayOfWeek in DayOfWeek.MONDAY..DayOfWeek.FRIDAY
if(isInWorkingHours && isWorkingDay) {
    //
}
```

And with an IDE like IntelliJ you get hints so that `..` range syntax is easily to understand you get:
[image]